# Threading in Python, control taken by the other thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

How do I multi-thread properly in `Python`?

I am trying to change the simple fork mechanism into a solution using the `threading` library (I think that forks causes some problems so I'm trying to replace them)

```
class CustomConsole(cmd.Cmd):
    db = DatabaseControl()
    bot = Bot(db)
    addPoints = AddPointsToActiveUsers(db)
    def do_startbot(self, args):
        botThread = threading.Thread(target=self.bot.mainLoop(),
                                     name='BotThread')
        botThread.daemon = True
        botThread.start()

    def do_startpoints(self, args):
        pointsThread = threading.Thread(target=self.addPoints.addPoints(), 
                                        name='PointsThread')
        pointsThread.daemon = True
        pointsThread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CustomConsole().cmdloop()
```

Both objects have infinite loops inside, but when i am starting one of them and i can't start the other one as it seems that the the thread is taking control of the terminal.

I think there could be problem with the custom console but I have no idea how to not give control over terminal to the thread but to leave it to the main thread and just run it in background.

In addition I have no idea why, but even if I delete the `objects.start()` lines, the threads are starting and I have no control over terminal again.

The code formatting is good, I just can't format it here properly

Comment: You're _calling_ your functions, not passing them to the `Thread` constructor.  Remove the extra `()`'s.

Comment: That solved the problem. Thanks a lot!